# Can't execute python3 on terminal (PYTHONPATH and PATH complications)

Tags: python-3.x, bash, macos

I installed the library `ase`. Since then I can't execute python3 on terminal neither run its python files. I found out with the command `which python3` command that with python3 is located at '/usr/local/bin/python3'. The libraries, including `ase`, are located at '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages' apparently.

See:

> pip3 install --upgrade git+https://gitlab.com/ase/ase.git@master

```
WARNING: The scripts ase, ase-build, ase-db, ase-gui, ase-info and ase-run are installed in '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

This is the error I got when I try to run `python3` on terminal:

```
Fatal Python error: init_sys_streams: can't initialize sys standard streams
Python runtime state: core initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ase/io/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ase'
```

I think that something has to be wrong at my .bash_profile file however, I'm not getting the error. Here is my edited .bash_profile:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ase:$PYTHONPATH
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:$PATH
```

Hope you can help me, thank you!

Update:

I changed my PYTHONPATH from:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ase:$PYTHONPATH
```

to:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

Now I can run python3 on terminal again, however I try to execute `ase` directly on the terminal it seems that the command is not found.

```
-bash: ase: command not found
```

I have already checked out the requires (`matplotlib`, `scipy`, `numpy`) and they are all installed. Seems that everything is wrong with the PATH. I don't know what could be.

The binaries files related to `ase` package are not anymore into this directory "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin". I don't know where they are since the installation was successfully done.

According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240037/why-did-pip-install-a-package-into-local-bin I redefined my paths to:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

and seems to be working, I already ran a program containing that package, however when I enter the folder '/usr/local/bin' I don't find those binary files.

If you can help me again I will be grateful.

Comment: To check if PYTHONPATH is the issue, you could try to start python with the `-E` option, e.g.: `python3 -E -c 'print("Hello, World!")'`

Comment: I did it, maybe it's not .bash_profile problem @vdavid